# print all the values of a group of objects without iterating through it

Tags: django, python-2.7

I want to print the values of the group of objects that return from the database.

I have tried like the following,

```
Products = productBll.listProduct(params)
print Products.__dict__
```

it will display like the following,

```
{'_result_cache': [Product: Product object, Product: Product object]}
```

But when i am doing like this ,

```
for prd in Products:
    print prd.__dict__
```

it showing all the contents in the Products objects

```
{'product_price': 0.0, 'right_side_min_depth': 0.0, 'short_description': u'', 'left_side_min_depth': 0.0, 'max_depth': 0.0, 'height_scale': 2.0, 'left_side_max_depth': 0.0, 'is_hinges': u'No', 'max_height': 1.04}
{'product_price': 0.0, 'right_side_min_depth': 0.0, 'short_description': u'', 'left_side_min_depth': 0.0, 'max_depth': 1000.0, 'height_scale': 1000.0, 'left_side_max_depth': 0.0, 'is_hinges': u'No', 'max_height': 1000.0}
```

But i want the above result without using the for loop.

Is there any way to do it by one line of code?

Comment: Why are you using `print` statements in Django code at all?

Comment: Don't you know what is the use of print statement in django?

Comment: No, I don't. It's pretty much never a good idea to write anything to stdout in a WSGI application. Use the logging module.

Comment: so give me the solution using the logging module. i just wanna see the contents in products object . thats it..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're looking for is a one-liner, here it is:

```
Products = productBll.listProduct(params)
print [prd.__dict__ for prd in Products]
```

Comment: so your saying that there is no keyword for showing the result for group of objects . we have to iterate using for loop right?...any way thanks buddy i have accepted your answer...

Comment: Well, there is no property, or built-in function for that matter. You can either write one yourself, or change the Product `__repr__` method so that it returns the same as `__dict__`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `values()`. Assuming your model is `Products` you can do

```
Product.objects.filter(your_filter_criteria).values()
```

this will give you list of dict per item selected.